# how do you filter a list of firewall rules by sourceRanges 0.0.0.0/0 using firewalls.list Method

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Im using the Method: [firewalls.list](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/firewalls/list?apix_params=%7B%22project%22%3A%22helloworld-273420%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%22sourceranges%3D%5B0.0.0.0%2F0%5D%22%7D) but when I try filtering I get
***"Invalid value for field 'filter': 'sourceranges=[0.0.0.0/0]'. Invalid list filter expression."***

```
from pprint import pprint
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

    service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    # Project ID for this request.
    project = "helloworld-273420"  # TODO: Update placeholder value.
    sourceRanges = "0.0.0.0/0"

    request = service.firewalls().list(project=project, filter=sourceRanges)
    while request is not None:
        response = request.execute()

        for firewall in response['items']:
            # TODO: Change code below to process each `firewall` resource:
            pprint(firewall)

        request = service.firewalls().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use instead a gcloud command to filter by sourceRanges:

gcloud compute firewall-rules list --filter="sourceRanges:(0.0.0.0/0)"

For more information check the usage of gcloud compute firewall-rules list:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/list

Cheers.

Comment: I understand the gcloud command works, but I am making a script to do the filtering but I get "sourceRanges:(0.0.0.0/0)" is a invalid filter expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
computeService = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
fireruleRequest = computeService.firewalls().list(project=project)
while fireruleRequest is not None:
    fireruleList = fireruleRequest.execute()
    for firewall in fireruleList['items']:
        if firewall['sourceRanges'] == ['0.0.0.0/0']:
            pprint(firewall) #prints all fields related to the firewall. Use firewall['field'] for a specific field
        #   print('error: nothing valid')
    fireruleRequest = computeService.firewalls().list_next(previous_request=fireruleRequest, previous_response=fireruleList)
```

The firewall.list method does not allow filtering of sourceRanges yet
refer to [firewall().list](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/python/latest/compute_v1.firewalls.html#list) docs for more info